# Why are some of my Next.js server components getting updated Zustand state but another isn't?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, zustand

I'm using Zustand to store user/session data. As shown, the root layout retrieves user/session data and sets the state. When a user logs in, signs up, or logs out, their session is updated using supabase, but I do not change the state when that happens. I instead window.location.replace("/") to the home page, which I believe reloads layout.tsx, which gets the new session info and stores it with Zustand.

For some reason when this happens, Header.tsx console logs the new (logged in) user data, but app/page.tsx does not. They are both server components, and are accessing the user info through `useSession.getState().user` the same way, so I can't figure out why the Header receives the user information, while the Home page thinks `user = null`. The home page only receives the updated state when I manually refresh the page.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Feel free to let me know if I'm going about this entirely wrong, as I'm new to Next.js and finding it confusing keeping track of what's going on client vs. server side.

**app/layout.tsx:**

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });

  // Set session state
  useSession.setState({
    user: (await supabase.auth.getUser()).data.user,
    session: await supabase.auth.getSession(),
  });

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Header />
        <main className="py-10">{children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**app/page.tsx:**

```
import { useSession } from "@/app/store/useSession";

export default function Home() {
  const user = useSession.getState().user;

  console.log("Home Page: ", user);

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      {user && <p>Welcome {user.email}</p>}
    </main>
  );
}
```

**useSession.tsx (Zustand):**

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { devtools } from "zustand/middleware";

interface SessionState {
  user: any;
  session: any;
  setUser: (user: any) => void;
}

export const useSession = create<SessionState>()(
  devtools((set) => ({
    user: null,
    session: null,
    setUser: (user) => set((state) => ({ user: user })),
  }))
);
```

**Header.tsx:**

```
import { useSession } from "@/app/store/useSession";

export default async function Header() {
  const user = useSession.getState().user;

  console.log("Header: ", user ? true : false);
  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex justify-between bg-white items-center p-2">
      <Link href="/">
        <h1 className="text-black text-3xl">Logo</h1>
      </Link>
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        {user ? (
          <LogoutButton />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Link href="/signup">Signup</Link>
            <Link href="/signin">Signin</Link>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

**signinForm.tsx:**

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email("Please enter a valid email address."),
  password: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Password must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
});

export function SignInForm() {
  const [error, setError] = useState<String | null>(null);
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
  });
  const router = useRouter();
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>();

  // On form submit
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) => {
    // Clear error
    setError(null);
    const email = values.email;
    const password = values.password;
    await supabase.auth
      .signInWithPassword({
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          setError(result.error.message);
        } else {
          router.refresh();
          window.location.replace("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="my-4 space-y-4">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="Email" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="password"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        {error && <div className="text-rose-600 p-2">{error}</div>}
        <Button className="w-full bg-blue-800 hover:bg-blue-900" type="submit">
          Sign In
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the component where you use `window.location.replace("/")`?

Comment: @RobinThomas Just updated to add that!

Comment: What if you replace `window.location.replace` with `router.push('/')` and remove the `router.refresh` before it?

Comment: @RobinThomas If I do that, the header also gets `user = null` as well as the Home Page. I believe window.location.replace causes the layout to refresh and store the session data in state, but router.push does not cause the layout to refresh.

Comment: As it should. You mention both are server components. Is `app/layout.tsx` (where you use `<Header />`), is that server component as well?

Comment: @RobinThomas Yeah `app/layout.tsx` is a server component. `signinForm.tsx`, however, is a client component.

Comment: If you import a server component into a client component, then that becomes a client component. Are you doing anything like that, that can make either of Header or Home, a client component?

Comment: @RobinThomas I just checked and I don't believe I am, no.

Comment: What if you remove `router.refresh` and `window.location.*` and replace with `router.reload("/")`?

Comment: @RobinThomas I will give that a shot, but all of this confusion makes me think I might be going about this whole process incorrectly.

Comment: @RobinThomas that did not work unfortunately